# Are cookie yields from plants affected by different soils?

Tags: cookie-clicker

Different soil types offer different modifiers for *"passive plant effects"*, ranging from -75% to +25%.

Some plants, such as Queenbeets and Bakeberries, have either a *"harvest when mature for +X minutes/hours of CpS"* or an *"explodes into up to X minutes of CpS at the end of lifecycle"* effect, which gives you cookies.

Are the yields from these plants affected by soil type's passive plant effect modifier?

In other words, do effects that involve harvesting a plant or waiting until it explodes count as passive plant effects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. All harvest bonuses are active and not passive. It was discussed here aswell along with others:

https://www.reddit.com/r/CookieClicker/comments/8d9wg2/201_garden_q_and_a/